# how can i read JSESSIONID with javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, cookies, jsessionid

i tried lots of method to read that variable from cookie with javascript but cant do.
Is there any special thing related with application server of Java that set cookie remotely?

Comment: What sort of things have you tried?

Comment: You can look at the cookies in the browser. Mind: there are two forms of session ids in Java: if cookies are disabled the session id is passed by the URL `...?JSESSIONID=...`; nicer is via a cookie (readable, bookmarkable URL); URL passing often is not done. The server app might use another name for the session ID; must be extra configured.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try a [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/). The JSESSIONID may be transmitted with the [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) flag. If so, a standardbrowser will not let you read that value.

Comment: +1 for relevant tool, +1 for HttpOnly, unfortunately I only have one upvote to give :(

Comment: you are right, standartbrowsers coulnt let you take a jsessionid, i will google it for fiddler2. thanks.