# Dojo Uploader using ajax plugin - spring security issue

Tags: spring, spring-security, dojo

I'm using Dojo uploader. It works just fine when it comes to HTML5 plugin. But if I force to use Flash plugin it fails with the next message:

"Server failed to respond"

On server side Spring security is throwing this:

```
    Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
22:33:06,375 DEBUG ty.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.traceNextValve(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:116)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is the flash plugin missing the session id?

Here is my js code:

```
forma = new Form({
            method: 'post',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            'class': 'Uploader',
            action: dojo.config.app.urlBase + 'upload/cargaArchivos'
        }, 'cargaForm');

        btnCargar = new Button({
            type: 'submit',
            label: 'Cargar'
        }, 'submitCarga');  

        btnReset = new Button({
            type: 'reset',
            label: 'Limpiar',
            onClick: function(){
                // limpiamos el array de archivos agregados
                uploader.reset();
                console.log(uploader.getFileList());
            }
        }, 'resetForm');

        uploader = new dojox.form.Uploader({
            id: 'uploader',
            name: 'uploadedfile',
            showInput: 'before',
            isDebug: true,
            url: dojo.config.app.urlBase + 'upload/cargaArchivos',
            multiple: true,
            force: 'flash',
            onComplete: function(respuesta){
                // Aqui se puede hacer algo con el objeto de respuesta que se devuelve.
                console.log(respuesta);
            },
            onChange: function(archivos){
                // Aquí se podrían listar los archivos en alguna tabla. 
                console.log(archivos);
            }
        }, 'uploader');
        uploader.startup();     
    }
```

### Note: I'm creating Uploader like 'new dojox.form.Uploader' coz I'm avoiding a known bug, see : [Programmatic Dojox Uploader - ajax upload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343652/programmatic-dojox-uploader-ajax-upload-not-working)

Update, I'm not using FileUploader coz it says has been deprecated, but Uploader.upload() method also receives a formData object.

First I'm trying is to read the cookie. Checking out the other request's header:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language es-mx,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
**Cookie    undefined=root; undefined=6%2C6%2F4; JSESSIONID=9F0E7745730639A3D0989C5D379A74FB**
Host    localhost:8080
Referer http://localhost:8080/sep-sajja-web/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

So the cookie name is JSESSIONID. But when I try

```
dojo.cookie('JSESSIONID');
```

It returns undefined... I'll keep trying.

Plain javascript:

```
document.cookie.split(";")
```

Just gives me back one cookie: ["undefined=6%2C6%2F4"]

Perhaps a permissions matter?

Update...
Yep, it looks like that -> [how can i read JSESSIONID with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486801/how-can-i-read-jsessionid-with-javascript)

Comment: try to dump the header 'Cookie' on the receiver (server) side during flash upload. You may need to override the action controller

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample of how the data is sent to server via the Flash plugin

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/form/FileUploader#server-side

I haven't been able to find informations in regards to whether cookies are sent (inherited from calling window) with the post - but there should be a possible solution as to send the sessionid via either GET query parameter or custom **POST data**.

```
new dojox.form.Uploader( {
    // ... your configurations
    postData: {
      sessionid: dojo.cookie('JSPCOOKIENAME_UNKNOWN_TO_ME')
});
```

As you might have noticed, springframework is not familiar to me, but from a brief search on howto create authentication based on a token, i think youre looking for similarities to the following. At least there will be a few class-buzzwords to search against

```
    Authentication authentication = this.authenticationProvider.authenticate(token);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

If you have enabled logins, i believe the **token** could be retreieved by

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = 
  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
User details = new User(username);
token.setDetails(details);
```

You will need to know which authenticationprovider is in use with your servlet and information is found in the webapp web.xml under `<filters>`

Comment: Yep, that is the idea. I'm failing reading the cookie though. Check out my Update above.